# MessagePackObject not attribute class. Which is correct, the decompile shows it's not

Tags: c#, msgpack

I need to transfer tons of data, mainly Vector3s and wanted to give MsgPack a try.

However after installing it, I can't set the proper attributes.

When I try to set the [MessagePackObject] attribute, I get an error that MessagePackObject is not an attribute class. Which is correct as its defined as

```
public struct MessagePackObject : IEquatable<MessagePackObject>, IPackable, IAsyncPackable
```

I tried the official release binaries and nu-get, both with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the wrong library. You're following the [Quick Start for neuecc/MessagePack](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#quick-start), but you're using the binaries for [msgpack/MessagePack-CLI](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/wiki/MessagePackObject) (see [source for `MessagePackObject`](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/blob/master/src/MsgPack/MessagePackObject.cs#L42)).

Install the [proper NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/messagepack):

```
 Install-Package MessagePack -Version 2.0.335
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!